# Portable Firefox for Mac

Tags: applications, firefox

If some person tells me how to have a nice [portable](http://www.portableapps.com) [Firefox](http://www.getfirefox.com) on my Mac, this person will have my eternal gratitude.

Comment: Would this do the job? http://www.freesmug.org/portableapps:firefox

Comment: @Alex — Alas, no. This link currently has a Firefox 4. Too old for me. We are at the Firefox 20s now.

Answer (score 3):

While I have written a portable version of Google Chrome for Windows, Chrome and Firefox have similar file structure, I'll give this semi tutorial a go..

First, copy your /Applications/Firefox.app to a folder named "Firefox" on a flash drive.

Now, locate a valid user profile for Firefox on your Mac (usually ~/Library/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/ or 
~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/ )

Copy a valid profile folder to this "Firefox" folder also.

Next, we will create a Bash script to properly open Portable Firefox, so..

Inside this "Firefox" folder create a "start.sh" with the following lines:

```
 /Volumes/<FLASHDRIVENAME>/Firefox/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -profile /Volumes/<FLASHDRIVENAME>/Firefox/<profile folder>
```

If you execute

```
$ bash /Volumes/<FLASHDRIVENAME>/Firefox/start.sh
```

You should be able to run Firefox on any Mac anywhere.

NOTE: Replace < FLASHDRIVENAME > with the mountable name of your flash drive.

Answer (score 2):

The version Firefox v22 for Mac at http://portableapps.com/node/37665 is stable.

I use it and it works great.